# How to abort a thread when it is sleeping

Tags: c#

I need to stop a thread ,but if it should sleep for  8 sec ,and I want to abort it ,it will continue sleeping for 8 sec,and only then stops.

Comment: Does it matter whether it is aborted during or after the sleep?

Comment: Have you considered waking it up? ie. using something that will force it out of the sleep?

Comment: It's a *really* bad idea to abort threads. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort

Comment: And it's (almost always) a really bad idea to Sleep() in a thread.

Comment: These guys are right; revisit your threading strategy entirely. Sleeping and aborting threads are almost never the right thing to do; doing them both together is a terrible idea. You should have a carefully architected solution whereby one thread can politely request another to take itself down, and the other thread guarantees to do so promptly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't (safely) abort a thread while it's asleep.  You should just check for your abort condition as soon as your blocking completes, and exit at that point.

There really is no disadvantage to this in most cases, anyways, as the thread will use very little resources while blocked.

If you must "abort" sooner, you could, instead, use a different mechanism for blocking.  Sleeping is rarely the correct option - a wait handle will likely be able to provide the same functionality, and give a means for the other thread to signal that it should stop blocking immediately.

Answer (score 15):

Use a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx):

```
ManualResetEvent mre=new ManualResetEvent(false);
//......
var signalled=mre.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8));
if(!signalled)
{
    //timeout occurred
}
```

elsewhere (before the 8 seconds is up):

```
mre.Set(); //unfreezes paused Thread and causes signalled==true
```

and allow the unblocked thread to terminate gracefully. `Thread.Abort` is [evil and should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort/1560567#1560567).

Answer (score 6):

Consider using the `System.Timers.Timer` class.  This is a timer that can be stopped if needed.

You can find some good instructions [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Timers)

Answer (score 2):

Use an AutoResetEvent [timed Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907.aspx) instead of `Sleep`, signal the [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) using [Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set.aspx) when you wish to interrupt the waiting thread, otherwise the timer expires.